# lost+found ディレクトリは削除して問題ない？

Tags: linux, filesystems

aws のインスタンスに、空のボリュームをアタッチして、 `mkfs.ext4` した後にマウントしました。

マウントした直後から `lost+found` ディレクトリが作成されていたのですが、これは削除してしまっても問題ないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

今回の場合、空のボリュームからということですので
そのフォルダには何も入っていないはずです。
ですので削除しても問題はないと思います。

そのフォルダは`fsck`(ファイルの整合性をチェックする)コマンドで作成され、
ファイル同士の対応関係が崩れてしまったファイルが保存されています。

- 複製元の環境と違う環境に複製され、ファイルの保存先を見失った
- 物理的に切断されてしまった場合に、ファイルの対応関係が崩れた
  (電源が突然切れた、ケーブル断線などなど)

などが原因で対応関係の崩れたファイルが保存されることがあります。

また、今後`fsck`が実行された場合に自動的に作成される可能性がありますが、
その場合は削除する前に削除して良いファイルか中身を確認するといいです。

Comment: まだクラッシュしていない今この瞬間には消してもいいと思いますが、いざクラッシュしたとき、リカバリーのために `fsck` が `mkdir lost+found` をしようとすることでリカバリーできなくなるファイルが発生することがあります。オイラは削除することをお勧めしません。作り直すときは `mklost+found` コマンドを使ってください。

Comment: このディレクトリ自体あって損は無いのでディレクトリ削除する意味は余りないのですけれど……まぁそもそもの話として、クラッシュするなりした場合にファイルの保存場所が分からない場合の緊急保管場所なので、スナップショットやバックアップを取っておけば最悪の状態は避けられると思いますけどね

Comment: 要するに保険なんですよね。いざという事態は発生しないにこしたことはないんだけど、発生したときのために普段からどんなコストを払うか？ってことで。ディレクトリ１個分のディスク容量なんてのはコスト０に近いので消さないほうをお勧めした次第。