# Linuxで空のディレクトリなのに容量が大きいのですが、なぜでしょうか？

Tags: linux, centos

CentOS6を利用していますが、ディスクの容量調査をしていて空のディレクトリにもかかわらす、8MBあるディレクトリを見つけました。
[このサイト](http://wiki.berrystyle.jp/?%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E6%B6%88%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E5%AE%B9%E9%87%8F%E3%81%8C%E6%B8%9B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C)にあるように以前、存在していたファイルのプロセス等が残っているのでしょうか？

```
[root@XXXXXX 20170501]# ls -al -h
合計 7.9M
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 7.9M  5月  2 00:05 2017 .
drwxr-xr-x 98 root root  20K  8月  4 11:05 2017 ..
```

Comment: [How do I reset the folder metadata size without recreating the folder?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325143)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

そのディレクトリに、以前、多数のファイルやディレクトリが存在していたのではないでしょうか。
ファイルシステムが Ext4 だと、一旦、ディレクトリの使用ブロックが増えた後、配下のファイル、ディレクトリを削除しても、該当ディレクトリの使用ブロックは減らないです。

Comment: Ext4でした。おしゃる通り、多数のファイルを保管しているディレクトリです。

Comment: 削除して問題ないディレクトリなので削除対応します

Answer (score 1):

具体的なディレクトリ名はわかりますか？ `lost+found` であるならそんなものです。
[lost+found ディレクトリは削除して問題ない？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/28465/)

突然の電源断などあった場合にディスクがクラッシュして、ファイル名の無い `inode` だけが残ったような場合のリカバーのために `lost+found` ディレクトリが使われます。このディレクトリはクラッシュする前に作っておかないと意味がありません。

Comment: シェルプロンプトを見ると、ディレクトリ名は `20170501` ではないですかね。

Comment: そうです。ディレクトリ名は20170501です。