# docker-composeでDockerfileのvolume設定を解除することは可能でしょうか

Tags: docker, docker-compose

volumeについて、`docker-compose.yml` には、`/var/lib/postgresql` 設定してあり、`Dockerfile` には `/var/lib/postgresql/data` が設定されています。
このとき、`Dockerfile`のvolume設定を`docker-compose.yml`から解除することは可能でしょうか。

### 解消したい問題の経緯

volume-driverにはconvoyを使用しているため、`lost+found` が存在すると、`initdb` にて次のようなエラーが出てしまう。これを回避しつつ、volume-driverにconvoyを使用したい。

> initdb: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty

上記問題を回避するためにとった対策と現実:
親ディレクトリである `/var/lib/postgresql` をvolumeとすれば解決できると考えた。
実際、 `/var/lib/postgresql` と `/var/lib/postgresql/data` にvolumeが使用された。
結果、`/var/lib/postgresql` にはデータが入らず、 `/var/lib/postgresql/data` のみにデータが記録された。
`/var/lib/postgresql/data` がvolumeとして設定されることを防げれば、`/var/lib/postgresql`にデータが入ると考えた。

---追記(2017/12/05 02:06) ここから---
上記解決したい問題については、[解決策](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/263) がありました。
環境変数 `PGDATA` に　`/var/lib/postgresql/data1` 等、異なるパスを記述することで解決できるようです。
解決の糸口は見つけましたが、表題の方法があるかどうかについて、気になるので、質問は削除せず、継続させていただきます。
---追記(2017/12/05 02:06) ここまで---

備考:
[lost+foundを消すことも検討した](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/28465/lostfound-%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AF%E5%89%8A%E9%99%A4%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) が、必要となることもあるため、削除という手段は使用していない。かつ、再度lost+foundが作成されたとき、DB一覧にlost+foundが表示されてしまう(8.x系の記憶なので、最新でどうであるかは未検証)。
[convoy側でlost+foundを抑止する可能性](https://github.com/rancher/convoy/issues/104)も考慮したが、issueの状態が更新されていないことから対応される見込みは薄いと判断した。

#### 各種ファイルおよびコマンド実行結果

Dockerfile

https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/d1725ffa8ba29ed7649bd453065eb392f63a3113/9.6/alpine/Dockerfile

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: work
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password1
    container_name: test_sv
    volumes:
      - data-db:/var/lib/postgresql
volumes:
  data-db:
# 事前にvolumeを作成している場合は以下のコメントを外す
#    external:
#      name: convoy_data-db
```

sudo docker inspect test_sv

```
[
    {
        "Id": "15aa91af404f082ecbaa6b397096f5f47b20640c62dcc9c635457bd2055a7975",
        "Created": "2017-12-04T14:28:11.596184856Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "postgres"
        ],
            ...
        "Name": "/test_sv",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "work_data-db:/var/lib/postgresql:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "work_default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            ...
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            ...
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "9e44772442f9a93457a01172a17816801601b43ffeaea009a1548d55d8efebde",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/9e44772442f9a93457a01172a17816801601b43ffeaea009a1548d55d8efebde/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "work_data-db",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/work_data-db/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "15aa91af404f",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password1",
                "POSTGRES_USER=work",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "PG_MAJOR=9.6",
                "PG_VERSION=9.6.5",
                "PG_SHA256=06da12a7e3dddeb803962af8309fa06da9d6989f49e22865335f0a14bad0aaaa",
                "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "postgres"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "postgres:9.6-alpine",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/postgresql": {},
                "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "9313f5bb20018503d6e305687c67a382e204b9e0911a3fdd66c54507ee9293ce",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "work",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "db",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.16.1"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
                    ...
        }
    }
]
```

#### 関連文章

[Compose ファイル・リファレンス - volumes, volume_driver](http://docs.docker.jp/compose/compose-file.html#volumes-volume-driver)

Comment: あるイメージに対して、 volume 設定を解除することは、 docker のレベルで無理だった記憶があります

Comment: やはりそうですか。1点お願いがあります。本件をクローズにもっていきたいので、上記内容で回答をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントよりは、回答の方が良いので、投稿します。

ソースはちょっと思い出せないのですが、 docker の image で volume が一度定義されていたとすると、少なくとも layer を重ねる方式では、 volume 指定をなかったことにすることはできなかったと記憶しています。

ですので、 volume のパスが気にくわない、やり直したいと思った場合には、 オリジナルの Dockerfile を取得し、 Volume 指定を外した上でイメージをビルドし直す、などが必要になると思っています。